# How to use file_get_contents to get Facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to use file_get_contents() function of PHP to retrieve page content of Facebook?

For example: I want to read the content of this link "https://www.facebook.com/search/str/teespring.com/stories-keyword/intersect/stories-publishers"

And here is my code:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("https://www.facebook.com/search/str/teespring.com/stories-keyword/intersect/stories-publishers");

echo $content;
```

But the result of this function is the page which required the authentication. It shows the login page of Facebook.

My question is how to read the content of any Facebook page by a PHP script? Of course it maybe required a Facebook account or Facebook app in the script.

Comment: No file_get_contents cannot send the correct headers to authenticate with Facebook, with that said you should look into wether the the Facebook API provide the same data as it will be easier to consume. See here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Comment: You must use Facebook API in this case.

Comment: Or use curl. You can add cookies etc. But the FB API will be more forgiving.

Comment: @hugo Tunius,  Kazi Masum Billah: Can you show me the API? I have searched in Facebook API document but not found the similar API that I want. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#search) I want the API that can list posts from any users (posts, share,...) that contain a specified keyword. Facebook has this functionality but not provided as an API. You can try by visit this link: https://www.facebook.com/search/str/teespring.com/stories-keyword/intersect/stories-publishers

Comment: @Twisty: I think use curl or cookies is very hard. But FB API has not API that I need for searching.

Comment: public post search is not available anymore with the api, and there is no other way to use it. scraping is not allowed btw.